# Question about punctuating the following sentence

Tags: punctuation

Are the commas correct in the following sentence.

In the essay A Plague of Tics, the author, David Sedaris, addresses the people who had to put up with his obsessive-compulsive behaviors when he was younger.

I am unsure about the comma after Sedaris.

Comment: If you have one before David Sedaris, you need one after it, but you'd do just fine leaving both of them out and only keeping the one after *Tics*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma after Sedaris is correct.

In multiple commas like you used, check to see if when the word or words before the comma if removed, there will still be meaning in the sentence. And yes there will in your sentence.

If you take 'the author' off the sentence will be meaningful. If it remains and you take 'David Sedaris' off too, the sentence will still be meaningful so you are correct.